# How to simulate stereo from a mono audio file with command line or python?

Tags: audio, stereo, voice, voice-manipulation, stereo-imaging

I'm trying to do stereo effect from a mono audio, not a copy of the mono track to another channel.

Some examples of stereoizing with [Audition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHgpYL7gJbw) and [Cubase 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8MAD4H8YkE).

Answer (score 0):

For a nice command line audio processing toolset, look into [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features).  You can write a short [script](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Scripts) to perform either of the methods shown in the two links you provided, as well as many other types of stereo processing, including impulse response convolution.  Click [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old but since I've ended up here when searching a solution to that problem I'll write what worked for me.

**SoX** works perfectly and converting a mono file to stereo (by duplicating the mono signal) is as simple as:

```
sox mono.wav stereo.wav channels 2
```

Make sure you have SoX installed, `mono.wav` being your input file and `stereo.wav` here is the name given to the output file (I would not recommend trying to work inplace -- input = output -- because it doesn't seem supported)

If you need to process an entire directory, you can do something like:

```
for f in *.wav
do
sox "$f" "{$f%.wav}-stereo.wav" channels 2
done
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Thanks for typing that out and sharing your experience.  That's what it's about.  If you read OP's question carefully, the examples they provided were cases of doing pseudo stereo processing such as comb filtering and micro delays to achieve a wider,  more "stereo sounding" result.  You can do all of that with SoX but I felt like OP should take ownership of actually doing the work, because only they can decide what sounds good to them for their application.  Frankly, I would never recommend doing that type of pseudo stereo treatment to voice (or any) recordings, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
May be this would help you to achieve the goal.


x, sr = librosa.load(path, sr = 48000)
dly = int(sr * 0.02) # 20ms delay
x_shftd = np.roll(x, shift=dly)
x_shftd[:dly] = 0
stereo = np.stack([x,x_shftd] ).T
```